# Best Way to Store Service Account Information

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing an application which will require an entry for a functional "service account" from active directory to be used via impersonation to perform certain functions of the application that require elevation. It would basically give users of the application abilities restricted by app functionality without having to give their account rights. In the past I've used an SHA1 encrypted hash and stored the encrypted password in the web.config. This is probably no where near as secure as other methods out there. The primary goal here is to be able to store the user id and password for the service account in the app without storing it in clear text anywhere. Any recommendations on this?

Comment: Are you concerned about external users of the site or admins/others that have access to the _server_? Seems like you could secure the app.config on the server side. So long as you don't explicitly provide a mechanism to expose the data publicly external users can't get to the web.config.

Comment: I'm mostly concerned about it being stored anywhere in clear text but SHA1 is a bit outdated and before I go doing it the same way but with SHA2 I wanted to see if there was some other best practice for this scenario.

Comment: I dunno why people are voting to close this, it's a perfectly valid question that isn't answered anywhere that I can find based on a number of searches.

Comment: Your question is basically querying for our opinions.  I think simply rephrasing the last sentence of your question will resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core's configuration setup allows multiple different sources for config: JSON, environment variables, etc. For storing secret information, some are better suited than others, so here's your main options:

1. User Secrets: this is a no-brainer for development. Any type of account information, API keys, etc. should be stored in user secrets in development. The chief problem is that this is only for development. As a result, you still need to find a solution for production.
2. Environment variables: While not encrypted, environment variables at least keep these settings confined to a particular server (where you might already be storing credentials for a service account like this anyways) and out of your source control. Still, some users may prefer a bit more security.
3. Azure Key Vault: Currently, this is the only distributed configuration option provided by ASP.NET Core that supports encryption. It's of course not free, but it's not that expensive, either. If you are already running in Azure, this is a no-brainer, but it's still a good option even if you're not.
4. Anything else you want to use: One of the nice things about ASP.NET Core is that everything is modular and swappable. You can use built-in configuration providers, those provided by third-parties, or even custom ones you create yourself. That latter fact, in particular, opens a world of possibilities to you, as if you simply take the time to write your own provider, you can actually continue to use something like a Web.config as you're used or integrate some other solution you want to use.